# EM2860 based video converter captures corrupted frames (how to debug?)

Tags: linux, video, v4l2

I designed my own analog video to USB converter. This converter is based on the TI TVP5150AM and the Empia EM2860. Shortly the converter works as shown in the diagram below.

```
         +---------+ ITU-R  +--------+
Analog   |         | BT.656 |        |
Video +--+ TVP5150 +--------+ EM2860 +---+  USB
         |         |        |        |
         +---------+        +--------+
```

As I am using Linux mint with kernel version 4.4 the drivers for both chips are already included. The good thing is that the hardware is recognized and I am able to get data from it. However the data is not as expected.

I put in an analog test image. The frames that I am able to capture look like this: [raw captured frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K31I.png).

The command I use to capture these raw frames is:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i /dev/video0 -frames:v:0 100 -c:v:0 ppm frame%03d.ppm
```

(note that I get the same kind of frames just opening the device with `mplayer`. This command is only to capture the separate frames)

The question is that I do not really know how to debug this issue. It looks that data is coming in, but is corrupted in some kind of way.

The following things I already figured out:

- The hardware seems to work fine. The TVP5150 is configured by the driver as expected. The ITU-R BT.656 interface is having real nice signals. In an earlier hardware revision I had trouble with reflections on this interface. At that time no frame was captured.
- `mplayer` drops a lot of frames. `ffmpeg` indicates a lot of duplicate frames. Both are on about the same ratio (4/5 of the frames are dropped or indicated as duplicates)

Could someone point me in a direction for debugging this issue?

**EDIT1:**

It looks like the settings of the TVP5150 are not correct. I found one register setting made me able to get color: [raw captured frame with color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTPMd.png)

**EDIT2:**

I had to set the driver explicitly to NTSC and use a very weird resolution (640x320) but frames are captured the right way now.

Comment: From the captured image: vertical retrace is wrong, possibly a 50/60 Hz issue - that would also explain the dropped frames. Color is not recognized, possibly PAL/NTSC issue, or wrong color carrier. Check the setup of both chips in detail, and see if they agree on the format, and this is the format you use for the test image.

Comment: I will check the settings in greater detail. I think I'll have to find a source where I know the format exactly. This is not the case right now. Although the TVP5150 has the ability to auto detect that, on this stage I don't think I can rely on that.